# SharePoint Designer 2010 removes onmouseover from code when saved

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, onmouseover

I have a problem that when I go to add the following image map code:

```
<area shape=\"poly\" coords="109,238,97,211,105,204,108,196,99,182,133,173,146,213,109,238" onmouseover="popup($('#alaska-table').html(), 400);" />
<area shape="poly" coords="175,180,157,160,145,160,135,148,148,146,152,120,165,120,164,132,191,137,194,158,176,173,175,180" onmouseover="popup($('#texas-table').html(), 400);" />
<area shape="poly" coords="89,134,79,133,65,116,58,89,56,80,60,70,73,73,70,89,91,123,89,134" onmouseover="popup($('#california-table').html(), 400);" />
<area shape="poly" coords="93,50,72,46,69,40,68,32,72,35,73,40,77,35,78,29,97,34,93,50" onmouseover="popup($('#washington-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="200,155,200,150,198,142,210,142,209,153,217,154,213,162,205,160,200,155" onmouseover="popup($('#louisiana-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="250,112,262,105,270,94,280,107,250,112" onmouseover="popup($('#virginia-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="232,220,232,219,234,219,234,220,232,220" onmouseover="popup($('#hawaii-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="246,226,246,225,248,225,248,226,246,226" onmouseover="popup($('#hawaii-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="260,231,262,231,262,232,260,232,260,231" onmouseover="popup($('#hawaii-table').html(), 400);" /> 
<area shape="poly" coords="266,247,266,238,274,243,266,247" onmouseover="popup($('#hawaii-table').html(), 400);" />
```

to my site, it removes the onmouseover entries, leaving only shape and coords entries.  I have added the load of the popup.js and jquery.js to the master page's  section, and it keeps that code.  Any recommendations?